# Trying to Loop and Add things to Iterable Java

Tags: java, iterable

I am trying to create a search page that allows you to use multiple terms and values keep having problems on finding a way to keep all the results. It works for one item but when I do multiple it only ends up displaying the last search. Here is my code for the controller and the class I am using to find the data.

```
    @PostMapping ("adv-search/results")
    public String displayAdvancedSearchResults(Model model , @RequestParam String searchType, @RequestParam String searchTerm) {

        Iterable<Recipe> recipes = null;
        String[] searchTerms = searchTerm.split(",");
        String[] searchTypes = searchType.split(",");

        for (int i=0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
            String sTe = searchTerms[i];
            String sTy = searchTypes[i];

            if (sTe.toLowerCase().equals("all") || sTe.equals("")){
                recipes = RecipeRepository.findAll();
            } else {
                recipes = RecipeData.findByColumnAndValue(sTy, sTe, RecipeRepository.findAll());
            }

        }

        model.addAttribute("columns", columnChoices);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Recipes with " + columnChoices.get(searchType) + ": " + searchTerm);
        model.addAttribute("recipes", recipes);

        return "adv-search";

    }
```

```
public class RecipeData {

    public static ArrayList<Recipe> findByColumnAndValue(String column, String value, Iterable<Recipe> allRecipes) {

        ArrayList<Recipe> results = new ArrayList<>();

        if (value.toLowerCase().equals("all")){
            return (ArrayList<Recipe>) allRecipes;
        }

        if (column.equals("all")){
            results = findByValue(value, allRecipes);
            return results;
        }
        for (Recipe recipe : allRecipes) {

            String aValue = getFieldValue(recipe, column);

            if (aValue != null && aValue.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
                results.add(recipe);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static String getFieldValue(Recipe recipe, String fieldName) {
        String theValue;
        if (fieldName.equals("name")){
            theValue = recipe.getName();
            System.out.println(recipe.getName());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("ingredients")){
            theValue = recipe.getIngredientList().toString();
            System.out.println(recipe.getIngredientList().toString());
        } else { //prints [com.launchcode.recipeproject.models.Tag@20] instead of tags
            theValue = recipe.getTags().toString().toString();
            System.out.println(recipe.getTags().toString().toString());
        }

        return theValue;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Recipe> findByValue(String value, Iterable<Recipe> allRecipes) {
        String lower_val = value.toLowerCase();

        ArrayList<Recipe> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Recipe recipe : allRecipes) {

            if (recipe.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lower_val)) {
                results.add(recipe);
            } else if (recipe.getIngredientList().toString().toLowerCase().contains(lower_val)) {
                results.add(recipe);
            } else if (recipe.getTags().toString().toLowerCase().contains(lower_val)) {
                results.add(recipe);
            } else if (recipe.toString().toLowerCase().contains(lower_val)) {
                results.add(recipe);
            }

        }

        return results;
    }

}
```

I was hoping by moving the addAttributes outside of the for loop that it would just add to recipes. I tried `recipes += RecipeData.findByColumnAndValue(sTy, sTe, RecipeRepository.findAll());` and `recipes += RecipeRepository.findAll();` but it complains saying that it needs to be changed to an Iterable or ArrayList which I have tried both and neither worked. Not sure what to do since the terms and types of the search are going through, but I can't find a way to store all the results and send them back to the page.

Comment: "it only ends up displaying the last search" In `displayAdvancedSearchResults` you assign the results of the search to `recipes`, so why do you expect previous searches to be returned as well?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well. I didn't expect the all the searches to be returned. I thought it would be as simple as adding the results to the existing results but whatever I try doesn't seem to work. I tried "+=" I tried "recipes = recipes + ..." I tried creating another Iterable and ArrayList to store results as it loops, but obviously I'm not doing it correctly. I cannot find anything online similar to my problem either. hence why I'm here

Comment: example like the user inputs 3 searchType/searchTerm pairs I wrote the code and got it to display the last input pair. I checked to make sure I was getting all the pairs and I am. I cannot get all the results of each pair together. They work seperately, but having trouble storing it in one place as it loops. That is my issue

Comment: Honestly, I'm new to coding. Just trying to get better to get a job. I'm still trying to figure how to even ask the right questions. I apologize if it was confusing! haha

Comment: I didn't read your code properly, no apology necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> `recipes = RecipeRepository.findAll();`

findAll() returns a reference (think 'address of a house') to a list object (think 'house' - `recipes` is a page in an address book with the address of a list on it. Not the list itself. `someOtherVariable = recipes` merely copies *the page in the address book*, not the entire list).

You overwrite your `recipe` address book page with the address to this list. That's how your entire loop works, hence, you end up with a page with a single address on it: The last house.

What you want is to add it all up. Which you can do, but, you don't get that for free. You program it. Make a list of your own and add all result to it:

```
var recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

...


if (sTe.toLowerCase().equals("all") || sTe.equals("")) {
  recipes.addAll(RecipeRepository.findAll());
} else {
  recipes.addAll(RecipeData.findByColumnAndValue(sTy, sTe, RecipeRepository.findAll());
}
```

`.` is java-ese for: Walk to the house at that address. So, with `recipe =`  you are just wiping out your address book page, that's no good. with `.addAll`, you are walking over there (you go to the house based on the address you have) and you yell at the house: ADD ALL! And hand *it* the address of that other list. Then the house does what it does. In this case, that's: Walk over there, make copies of everything in that other house and bolt it onto itself. Which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I did know it was doing that but couldn't find a way to add to it like you said. It did want to use 'recipes.addAll((Collection<? extends Recipe>) RecipeRepository.findAll());' and 'recipes.addAll(RecipeData.findByColumnAndValue(sTy, sTe, (ArrayList<Recipe>) RecipeRepository.findAll()));' and it did work. Do you know why I have to add the collection and arraylist parts?

Comment: The answer already explains it: If you want the concept of 'toss all results together', you need a place to store that: Your own list.